# UIView init with coder causes a recursion

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to embed a UIView I've prepared, which is located in a xib file, to a storyboard.

What I've done so far is:

```
class TestUIView : UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak private var firstButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak private var secondButton: UIButton!

    // MARK - Lifetime

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let view = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("TestUIView", owner: self, options: nil).first as! TestUIView

        self.addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

But for some reason I get bad access memory exception.
From looking into stack trace I see a whole bunch of calls to initWithCoder
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH6Am.png
I'm not sure why NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed causes this, any ideas?

Comment: Presumably the nib file contains an instance of a `TestUIView`, so when`loadNibNames` loads the nib, it will instantiate a `TestUIView` instance by called `init(coder)` which loads the nib and so on until the recursion causes the stack to explode. why are you loading the nib within `init(coder)`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turn's out what I have done wrong is how I prepared the .xib file, I've set the View itself, instead of the file owner to TestUIView class.
After changing the file owner(and reseting the constraints), everything worked fine.

Comment: Mark your answer as resolved so it can help other people :)

Answer (score 8):

For future seekers....

**Brief :** The recursive call of `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` occurs when you accidentally set your custom view class in identity inspector of your ContentView.

When the compiler tries to load your Nib file(the owner view) it first needs to initiate your `ContentView` (see the following picture) and if you have mistakenly set the custom class for your `ContentView` or any of its subviews, it goes through another Nib loading process and stuck in a recursive infinite loop.

To do it the right way, you should only set your custom view class for the view in Placeholder’s part. Please see 1 and 2 in the following picture.

In this picture I have defined a custom class named `CardView`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just defined the way to build a `TestUIView` that contains a `TestUIView` that contains a `TestUIView` that contains a `TestUIView`...

Your don't have to call

```
let view = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("TestUIView", owner: self, options: nil).first as! TestUIView
```

from

```
init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

This way you are creating an infinite loop because `loadNibNamed` will automatically call the `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`.

Just remove these lines

```
let view = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("TestUIView", owner: self, options: nil).first as! TestUIView
self.addSubview(view)
```

Comment: But still, how do I connect the nib to the class?
Removing those classes, leaves my outlets unset.

Comment: btw, this is where I got this idea from: http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6